# How can a chrome extension save an object in a webpage without having to re-request it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Let's say that my user will be using a website that periodically displays a new image.  I want to be able to download this image without having to send another network request to retrieve it (e.g. from the cache or intercepting the original request and writing the response to disk, something like that).  Is this possible?  If so, how would I go about adding this feature to my extension?